# Automatic editing of WPF datagrid content when datagrid-cell gets focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid in WPF with a **DataGridTextColum** and a **DataGridTemplateColum**.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="4*" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="dataGridColumnDescription" 
Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}">
</DataGridTextColumn>

<DataGridTemplateColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource CellEditing}" IsReadOnly="False" Width="*" Header="Value" 
CellEditingTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myCellEditingTemplateSelectorValue}" 
CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myCellTemplateSelectorValue}">
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The CellTemplateSelectors return a DataTemplate with a TextBlock for the the Celltemplate resp. a TextBox for CellEditing!

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="dGridStringValueTemplate">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="dGridStringValueTemplateEditing">
    <TextBox TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1" Text="{Binding Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Now I want to automatically Focus the TextBox when the DataGridCell gets the focus. The user should be able to edit the TextBox content without doubleclicking the cell.**

I found this article:

[DataGrid Tips & Tricks: Single-Click Editing](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing&ProjectName=wpf)
where I can get the Current DataGridCell, but how can I access the content to give the Textbox the focus to edit the content?

This is my style:

```
<Style x:Key="CellEditing" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="myDataGridMain_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"></EventSetter>
</Style>
```

This is my event handler:

```
private void myDataGridMain_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;     // cell ist not null

    DataGridTemplateColumn col = cell.Column as DataGridTemplateColumn; //col is not null

    DataTemplate template = col.CellTemplate;  //this is null
}
```

**How can I get the textbox with that event handler?**

Comment: When you want your grid to be editable all the time why you want editing template? just add cell template with textbox in it and change style of textbox itself this way u dont have to write focus stuff

Comment: @WPFKK That wouldn't work since the datagrid wouldn't switch to "edit mode", therefore the input value wouldn't be bound to source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed it, not the best solution but it works...
When Cell gets focus I set it to editing mode.

```
private void myDataGridMain_OnFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
    if (cell != null)
        cell.IsEditing = true;
    //var test = FindVisualChild<TextBlock>(cell);
}
```

On Keydown I search for the visual child and give the focus.

```
private void myDataGridMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;

            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {   //give cell the focus
                cell.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                if ((cell != null))
                {
                    TextBox textbox = FindVisualChild<TextBox>(cell);
                    if (textbox != null)
                    {   //TextBox has benn found
                        if ((textbox as TextBox).IsFocused == false)
                        {
                            (textbox as TextBox).SelectAll();
                        }
                        (textbox as TextBox).Focus();
                    }

                    CheckBox chkbox = FindVisualChild<CheckBox>(cell);
                    if (chkbox != null)
                    {   //Checkbox has been found
                        (chkbox as CheckBox).Focus();
                    }

                    ComboBox combbox = FindVisualChild<ComboBox>(cell);
                    if (combbox != null)
                    {   //ComboBox has been found
                        (combbox as ComboBox).Focus();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Find Visual Child!

```
public static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is T)
            return (T)child;
        else
        {
            T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: How did you subscribe to the OnFocus event for each cell?

Answer (score 20):

This seems to work :

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox  FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In combination with a template-selector this does not work :(

Comment: I have a complex DataGrid with combos & textBoxes. This sample solved my issues for all cell types.

Comment: @HamedR Great :)

Comment: I'm using a template selector, and the above worked for me.

Comment: @HamedRezaei Interesting.  When I add the focus manager to my XAML ever column with a text box shows the text box focused and I still have to tab twice.

Answer (score 5):

This approach works for me. It uses the fact that the `DataGrid` will always create a new instance of the template when the editing starts:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty}" 
                 Loaded="TextBox_Loaded"></TextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

and in the code behind:

```
private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).Focus();
    ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
}
```

As an added bonus, it also selects all text in the cell. It should work no matter how you enter the editing mode (double click, single click, pressing F2)

Answer (score 0):

the simple answer for that  create new control derived from datagrid control

```
  using System.Windows.Controls;

   public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
   {

    protected override void OnSelectedCellsChanged(SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //to make sure cell is selected
        var cells = e.AddedCells.FirstOrDefault();
        if (cells != null)
        {
            this.BeginEdit();

        }
        base.OnSelectedCellsChanged(e);
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hisham's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2114046/hisham) suggestion works perfectly for me, but I would use `OnCurrentCellChanged` instead, since `OnSelectedCellsChanged` will not work when the `SelectionUnit` is `CellOrRowHeader`. In the latter case `BeginEdit()` would only be triggered when selection moves to a cell in another row. Stepping left or right will not trigger the event at all.

Also, it is probably advisable to add a DependencyProperty to the custom control and check against it before triggering `BeginEdit()`, to prevent this behavior if so desired (as done by other DataGrids, such as XCeed). But this is not a critic - just something that I usually do.

```
    protected override void OnCurrentCellChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Make sure a cell is selected and only enter edit mode
        // if this is the desired behavior 
        if (CurrentCell != null && EditTrigger == EditTriggers.CellsCurrent)
        {
            this.BeginEdit();
        }
        base.OnCurrentCellChanged(e);
    }
```