# How to skip WPF DataGrid cell focus and go to control inside it?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

In a WPF project I have a button in a DataGridCell. When I press tab it will focus the cell first and then the button inside this cell. How can I skip cell focus?

The columns are dynamic and I don't know which column has a button or textbox.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since a button in a `DataGrid` is none of the standard column types, I suppose you're already using the `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

Additionally to the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate`, set the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle` with a style to set the `DataGridCell.IsTabStop` property to `False`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Header="CheckBoxColumn" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text}" Header="TextColumn" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ButtonColumn">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Text" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the DataGrid when you edit a cell and press Enter key, goes to the next row and also if you define IsTabStop=False, the focus goes on the cell and not to the templated inner control. It's strange, I know, and I'm facing this problem now, I the only way I see to resolve it is to handle the GotFocus DataGridCell event.

Comment: There are some questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10404681/1843468) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28168645/1843468) in this direction, not sure if they help you. If not, ask a new question, make sure to include the whole `DataGrid` definition, and maybe link to this and those two questions and specify why they don't work for you.

Comment: The solution that you have provided it's OK to me for the problem asked, but I warned @j.kahil that this solution it's not enough for the Enter Key behaviour of any `DataGrid`
For that problem I use to handle the `GotFocus` event. That's all

Comment: If you want Enter key to act as Tab, besides using the accepted answer you could take a look at this link (I couldn't post the code as is marked as too long):
 
[link](http://madprops.org/blog/enter-to-tab-as-an-attached-property/)

In case the link stops working, search for EnterKeyTraversal . Add the class to your project and add EnterKeyTraversal.IsEnabled="True" at DataGrid to enable it.